# How to run geolocator in background with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location, geolocator

I try to use geolocator run in background with flutter like this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator). I put the code in function _getlocation() and change onPressed to call _getlocation like this.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _getlocation() {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
          distanceFilter: 100,
          forceLocationManager: true,
          intervalDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
          //(Optional) Set foreground notification config to keep the app alive
          //when going to the background
          foregroundNotificationConfig: const ForegroundNotificationConfig(
            notificationText:
                "Example app will continue to receive your location even when you aren't using it",
            notificationTitle: "Running in Background",
            enableWakeLock: true,
          ));
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      locationSettings = AppleSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        activityType: ActivityType.fitness,
        distanceFilter: 100,
        pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: true,
        // Only set to true if our app will be started up in the background.
        showBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
      );
    } else {
      locationSettings = LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 100,
      );
    }

    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream =
        Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
            .listen((Position? position) {
      print(position == null
          ? 'Unknown'
          : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
    });
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getlocation,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

when I click FloatingActionButton it show error like this.

```
E/FlutterGeolocator( 9580): Geolocator position updates stopped
E/FlutterGeolocator( 9580): There is still another flutter engine connected, not stopping location service
```

How to run geolocator in background with Flutter?